# If $O^{2'}(G) / N$ simple for normal $2'$-subgroup, then $G$ has no subgroup of index $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group. A group is called a $2'$-group if its order is odd. Also $O^{2'}(G)$ denotes the smallest normal subgroup such that $G / O^{2'}(G)$ has odd order.

> If there exists some normal $2'$-subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $O^{2'}(G) / N$ is simple, then $G$ could not contain a subgroup of index two.

Is this true, and if so why?

Comment: The largest normal subgroup of $G$ of odd order is usually denoted by $O_{2'}(G)$, and $O^{2'}(G)$ denotes the smallest normal subgroup such that $G/O^{2'}(G)$ has odd order.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was confusing these notions. Anyway, I thought about it again, and still cannot solve it, I see that if $|G : U| = 2$ for some $U \le G$ we must have $G = O^{2'}(G)U$, but I cannot connect it to the simplicity of $O^{2'}(G) / N$ to arrive at a contradiction somehow, could you please give a hint?

Comment: Why not look at some small groups to see if you can find a counterexample?

Comment: Yes. I thought I have found one: $C_2 \times C_3$. Then $O^{2'}(G) = C_2$ and $N = C_3$, and $O^{2'}(G)N / N \cong C_2$, but clearly it has a subgroup of index two. But what makes me wondering is that this comes from a paper, and there they definitely write $O^{2'}(G) / N$ without supposing $N \le O^{2'}(G)$, so this notion would not make sense as a factor group. Might this be a typo in the paper or does it make sense to write it that way?  Btw I thought the above "fact" where used there implicitly, but now I know its not true :)

Comment: Even $C_2$ is a counterexample. I was wondering whether they might have meant the $O^{2'}(G)/N$ is a nonabelian simple group. Then the claim would be true. (In fact $O^{2'}(G)/N = C_2$ is the only simple group that leads to the statement being wrong.)

Comment: That sounds interesting, I would like to see the proof if possible...? Maybe that the factor group is nonabelian might follow from other assumptions, although I do not see them yet. To give some background, this is Lemma 5.4. from http://conway1.mathematik.uni-halle.de/~waldecker/MagaardWaldecker2fp.pdf

Comment: Well, we have $1 \le N < O^{2'}(G) \le G$, where $N$ and $G/O^{2'}(G)$ have odd order, so if $G$ has a subgroup of index $2$ then $O^{2'}(G)/N$ must have one too!

Comment: @DerekHolt: Can you please give some details? I just see that if $|G:U|=2$ we have $G = UO$, with $O := O^{2'}(G)$, $|O : U\cap O| = 2$ and by simplicity applied to $(U\cap O)N/N \unlhd O/N$ that $(U\cap O)N = O$ or $U\cap O \le N$...

Comment: More generally if a group $G$ has a subnormal series $G \unrhd G_1 \unrhd  \cdots \unrhd G_1=1$ and a normal subgroup of prime index $p$, then at least one of the quotients $G_i/G_{i+1}$ must have a normal subgroup of index $p$.

Comment: Okay, I tried: If $G \unrhd G_1 \unrhd \ldots \unrhd G_k = 1$ and $N \unlhd G$ has prime index $p$ then $|G : N| = |G/N : G_1N/N| \cdots |G_kN/N : N/N| = |G : G_1N||G_1N : G_2N| \cdots |G_kN : N|$, and so for some $i$ we have $p = |G_iN : G_{i+1}N|$ with $G_i \unrhd G_{i+1}$. But how to construct a subgroup of $G_i / G_{i+1}$ from there, no matter what I try I do not get it?

Comment: @DerekHolt: Okay, guess I found it!! But still would be very interested in why we have $N < O^{2'}(G)$??? I do not see how to use the odd assumption that $O^{2'}(G)/N \ne C_2$ to show it??? As how I showed the other, set $B := G_i(N \cap G_{i+1})$, then $BN = G_iN$ and by using Dedekind's law $G_i/B = G_i/(G_i(N\cap G_{i+1})) = G_i/(G_iN \cap G_{i+1}) \cong G_iG_iN/G_{i+1}G_iN = G_iN/G_{i+1}N$ :)

Comment: Oh I forgot, and $G_i / B \cong G_i/G_{i+1} / B/G_{i+1}$ and so $B/G_{i+1}$ is the required subgroup of $G_{i}/G_{i+1}$.

Comment: Oh, I see now I wrote it up wrongly but cannot edit anymore: we must set $B := G_{i+1}(N \cap G_i)$ and then apply Dedekind and the isomorphism theorems!

Comment: I don't understand your question about why $N < O^{2'}(G)$. That was part of your assumptions!

Comment: Okay, then this is assumed! I wrongly misinterpreted the statement that if they write $O^{2'}(G) / N$ that somehow $N \le O^{2'}(G)$ is implied, but then it might mean that it is supposed to hold.